# fireEvent doesn't click button on React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, testing-library

I'm writing tests for a React component. It's a timer that starts counting down when you press a button, then stops when you press the same button. I have a test case that tries to press the pause button, wait a second, then press the pause button again, checking the timer to make sure that a second has elapsed:

`Timer.test.js`

```js
render(<Timer />)
const pauseButton = screen.getByText('pause')
const timerOutput = screen.getAllByRole('heading')[1]

describe('Timer', () => {
  test('Timer starts counting down when unpaused', done => {
    function fetchTime(callback) {
      fireEvent.click(pauseButton)
      setTimeout(
        fireEvent.click(pauseButton),
        1250
      )
      return callback(timerOutput)
    }

    function callback(data) {
      try {
        expect(data).toHaveTextContent('24:59')
        done()
      } catch(error) {
        done(error)
      }
    }

    fetchTime(callback)
  })
})
```

The problem is, the test doesn't seem to be hitting click on `pauseButton` the way I want it to. Jest tells me in the terminal when I run my test that `timerOutput` turns out to be `'25:00'` rather than `'24:59'`, and it seems as if the component failed the test. But this is a problem with the test, not the component; when I run the app in my browser and press the button myself, it works the way it should. How do I get this test to work properly, and hit the buttons the way I want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to have an accurate answer with few information about the component itself.

First I would recommend use `async` arrow function inside `test()` whenever you need to handle async calls so you don't rely in callback hell.

Besides that, I would try to use `jest.useFakeTimers()` so you can advance the setTimeout timer in order to test properly. It seems that your second `fireEvent.click` never gets fired since the test checks it synchronously.

And I just noticed you requested the `timerOutput` at first but didn't request it after the click events.

I would suggest something like:

```
test('Timer starts counting down when unpaused', async () => {
      jest.useFakeTimers();
      fireEvent.click(pauseButton)
      setTimeout(
        () => {fireEvent.click(pauseButton)},
        1250
      )
      jest.runPendingTimers(); // This would run the above function
   
        expect(screen.getAllByRole('heading')[1]).toHaveTextContent('24:59')
    }
  })
```

Indeed, the expect statement would be better from a user perspective assertion, like:

```
expect(screen.getByText("24:59")).toBeVisible();
```

Since you don't matter about the HTML elements that contains that text content